# Change of basis- vector space of polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra

Given is the **vector space of Polynomials of degree $\le3$** and the basis
 $$\mathcal{B}_2 = \left\lbrace1,x-1,x^2-3x+2,x^3-6x^2+11x-6\right\rbrace$$
Furthermore the linear mapping
$$L: p(x) \rightarrow p'(x) + p(x)$$

I am looking for the transformation-matrix of $L$ w.r.t $\mathcal{B}_2$

---

For the regular basis $\mathcal{B}_1=\left\lbrace1,x,x^2,x^3\right\rbrace$ this transformation matrix should be given by
$$L_{\mathcal{B}_1}=\begin{pmatrix} 1&1&0&0 \\ 0&1&2&0\\0&0&1&3\\0&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$
Is this correct?

---

However, I am actually looking for $L_{\mathcal{B}_2}$

If I would have a *basis-change-matrix* (I am sorry, I do not know the correct english word for it, but I think it is clear what I mean) donated $S$ then it should hould
$$L_{\mathcal{B}_2} = S^{-1}L_{\mathcal{B}_1}S$$
Is this correct either?

---

I tried with 
$$S=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&0\\-1&1&0&0\\2&-3&1&0\\-6&11&-6&1\end{pmatrix}$$
But the result I get seems to be wrong.

Comment: $S$ should be the transpose of what you have written there.  For example the last column ought to be $[ -6, 11, -6, 1]^\top$, expressing the last basis vector of $\mathcal(B)_2$ in terms of the standard basis.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest if you simply perform the given linear map $L$ to the new basis ($\mathcal B_2$) and write it as a linear combination of polynomials from this same $\mathcal B_2$.

E.g., for the third column of the matrix, apply $L$ to $b_2:=(x^2-3x+2)$, getting
$$L(b_2)=b_2+2x-3=b_2+2b_1-b_0\,.$$